# Lose control to my dual boot (grub) after disabling secure boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I just setup Ubuntu inside my HP, so usually I managed to change whenever I want by restart. During my Ubuntu setup I had problem with network driver, which ask me to disable secure boot first. Then I proceed to disable my secure boot in BIOS but after saving changes I cannot access my GRUB thus cannot go to my Ubuntu. Hope anyone with experience can help

Comment: You haven't said what release of Ubuntu/Kubuntu you are talking about. If you installed with secure-boot off, you're install should work with secure-boot off, but it reads like you've changed options after install and now it won't boot, but it's somewhat unclear sorry.

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu (18.04) during installation secure boot still on which i don't realize. Later on i disable it then this happen

Answer (score 1):

for some reasons, my GRUB got replaced by Windows Boot Manager after disabling Secure Boot

```
// this how i check
run CMD as administrator => bcdedit
```

Then managed to fix it by running

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Here the original post that i found :-
https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/